# Sending control characters to LCD over serial

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, lcd

I have code that I used to write to an LCD screen in `Python 2`, it worked fine. I could control things like cursor, colour, brightness, display the text I need and update it. I've since converted my code to `python 3` and that has broken things, the screen has the correct text but a lot of gibberish characters now. It's also not changing to the right colour, writing things in the wrong place and so forth. I can write text manually fine, so that works, it seems that the issue lies in writing control characters.

Working in `Python 2`:

```
def __write(self, value):
    self.__serial.write(str(value))

# for commands that need control characters, start with 0xfe etc
def __write_array(self, array_values):
    array_values.insert(0, 0xfe)
    for item in array_values:
        self.__write(chr(item))
```

For `Python 3` I have changed the write function to send bytes:

```
def __write(self, value):
    self.__serial.write(str(value).encode())
```

This works fine, writes to the screen:

```
self.__serial.write("test".encode())
```

Here is an example of one of the functions, changing the LCD colour (for instance `0xd0, 0, 255, 0` would be green) and the array for __write_array() is `[254, 208, 0, 255, 0]`:

```
def set_background_color(self, value):
    _check_color(value)
    self.__state.background_color = value
    red = value[0]
    green = value[1]
    blue = value[2]
    self.__write_array([0xd0, red, green, blue])
    self.__state.background_color = value
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

[image: Example of characters that appear on the screen:]

Example of some data written as a string to a file:

`�þ�~Q^P^B�þT�þK�þ�~Y�~H�¾P�~H�þ@System          Booting             �þ�~P^@^@�ÿ þX�þH�þH�þH                               �þ�~P^@^@�ÿ�þ�~Y�~H�¾P�~H�þH�þH       �þ�~P^@^@�ÿ�þ�~Y�~H�¾P�~H�þ�~P^@�ÿ^@�þH�þHa`

Any idea of what I need to change here?

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea; in Python 2 there was no difference between byte strings and character strings, so `chr(x)` was the correct way to get a byte from 0 to 255.  Usually `.encode()` is the proper way to convert a string to bytes, but not in your case.  You want exact byte values, but you're introducing a character set conversion that mangles your byte stream.  The way around this is to avoid the conversion to characters completely and convert directly to bytes.

```
def __write(self, value):
    self.__serial.write(bytes([value]))

# for commands that need control characters, start with 0xfe etc
def __write_array(self, array_values):
    array_values.insert(0, 0xfe)
    for item in array_values:
        self.__write(item)
```

There are more efficient ways to do this, but it should get you started.

To see how you were going wrong, here's a comparison:

```
>>> chr(0xd0).encode()
b'\xc3\x90'
>>> bytes([0xd0])
b'\xd0'
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's definitely closer. I noted another small issue before this and the screen could then be controlled, albeit still sending the mangled bytes to the screen. With your fix the extra characters disappear, but the screen no longer is accepting controls correctly, it doesn't changes colour etc and prints numbers to the screen, presumably related to the colour codes I'm sending. Getting closer!

Comment: Ah yes I have it now, what the loop does in that case is either print ints or if encoded create a bytes array of that size, what I want is chr(item).encode("latin1")) as a quick fix, so the bytes aren't mangled, or else send [0xd0] instead of `0xd0` which the for loop was doing wrong